How do I read what the memory limit is in R?
This is related to the question of how to increase the memory limit on macOS, "R on MacOS Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)". I was wondering, is there some way to read this value in R so that my program can adapt to the upper bound during execution instead of running into a memory limit error?
I understand that the value can be set in an .Renviron file but I am not sure if this file is always in the same location, or if it is even required in all cases...

Check out the memuse package. It should have all the memory use and free memory information you need.

The documentation on memory in base R has the following to say about R_MAX_VSIZE.

The maximal vector heap size can be set with the environment variable R_MAX_VSIZE. An attempt to set a lower maximum than the current usage is ignored. Vector heap limits are given in bytes.

(emphasis mine)
However, as previous answers on StackOverflow have discussed (1, 2), the value can also be given as 100Gb or 32Mb.
This is because the environment variable is passed into R_Decode2Long function (see the definition in the source code).
You can adapt this code to manually parse the environment variable, or read the parsed limit using gc() which looks at the first non-numerical character to determine whether to multiply the numerical portion by 1, or various powers of 1024.
> gc()
          used (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb) limit (Mb) max used  (Mb)
Ncells 1192165 63.7    2426177 129.6         NA  2426177 129.6
Vcells 2756215 21.1    8388608  64.0     102400  3597156  27.5
> gc()[10]
[1] 102400
> gc()[10] * 1024^2
[1] 107374182400


R_MAX_VSIZE is an environment variable so you can access it using Sys.getenv().
> Sys.getenv("R_MAX_VSIZE")
100Gb

This is also related to the R question about accessing environment variables: "How can I make R read my environmental variables?"
